# How can I make a check box default to being "checked" in Rails 1.2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I make a check box default to being "checked" when it is initially displayed?

I've not found a "Rails" way to do this (that works) so I did it with JavaScript. Is there a proper way to do this in Rails? I'm using Rails 1.2.3.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you're using `check_box` in the context of a form, then the check box will show whatever value that field has.

```
@user = Person.find(:first)
@user.active = true
check_box 'user', 'active'  #=> will be checked by default
```

If you're using `check_box_tag`, the third parameter is the initial state ([`check_box_tag` doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag)):

```
check_box_tag "active", 1, true
```

Comment: I'm not reading/writing check_box value to the db, so switching to check_box_tag and using the true switch solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The _tag methods are for non-model forms.  The non-_tag ones are.

Comment: @wesgarrison I'm using a check_box_tag like this <%= check_box_tag "benificiary_id[#{b.id}]",b.id,:name => "benificiary_id[]"%> here how do i check whether any record checked or not during update? by default my update action taking all check box values even if some of them unchecked :(

Comment: @shreekumar s: Two year old question, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 51):

**Rails 3.x**

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.check_box :subscribe, {checked: true, ...}
```

This sets the checked state to true and should work fine.  Note the ruby 1.9.x syntax of the hash, for ruby 1.8.x use hash tag format {:checked => true, ...}

Comment: I found this to be useful when pulling from a DB record

Comment: this works with Rails 2.3.11 as well. Just use Ruby 1.8.7 hash syntax.

Comment: Works in 4.2 as well.

Comment: I don't know it works in 3.x too, but in 4.2 you don't need `{}`. So you can just code `f.check_box :subscribe, checked: true`

Comment: Works for rails 6.0.1

Answer (score 7):

**Simple**

```
<%= f.check_box :subscribe, checked: "checked" %>
```

Answer (score 6):

In your controller's new action, try:

```
@user = User.new(:male => true)
```

Where :male is the attribute you want checked by default on the `/users/new` pages. This will pass the `:male` attribute to the view with a value of `true`, resulting in a checked box.

Answer (score 6):

I was shocked that none of the answers solve 100% of the problem.
As all suggested solutions will give `checked` result on edit form, even if the user unchecked the checkbox.

`<%= f.check_box :subscribe, checked: @event.new_record? || f.object.subscribe? %>`

Works for rails 4 +, not tested below.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This works on Rails 2.3.x and Rails 3.0.x!**

On action new in the controller, the check box is set to true.

```
# in the controller
def new
  @user = Person.find(:first)
  @user.active = true
end
```

In the form: the check box is checked on creation (by call new) but if the validation fails the check box remains set with the value that the user has post.

```
# in the view
<%= form_for ..... |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.check_box :active %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

An other way, **but not so good** (if you want to change the logic you have to make a new migration) is to set *:default => 1* in the migration of the given model and attribute.

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :people do |t|
      ...
      t.boolean    :active,             :null => false,
                                        :default => 1
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :people
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in that way.

Add hidden field with value 0 ABOVE check_box_tag

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :subscribe, '0' %>
<%= check_box_tag :subscribe, '1', params[:subscribe] != '0' %>
```

On server check with `!= '0'`

```
subscribe = params[:subscribe] != '0'
```