# Data which user saved make the initial value of checkbox

Tags: ruby, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-5

#### Background

In my app, users can choose multiple languages which they're able to speak on their profile edit page **(users/edit.html.erb)** from checkbox. Many-to-many relation is already written, so multiple data can be saved properly.

Now, when users came back to their profle edit page, all the checkbox are displayed in a blank. I would like to display languages with **"checked"** which user chose and saved.

#### users/edit.html.erb

```
<li>
 <div class="col-1">Spoken languages:</div>
   <div class="col-2">      
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="1">Japanese</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="2">English</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="3">Chinese</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="4">Spanish</label>
  </div>    
</li>
```

#### What I tried to do

I searched this kind of function, but I only found how to make a specific initial value `(such as always check "English")`. I would be grateful if someone give me advice.

#### Version

ruby 2.6.4p104
RubyGems 3.0.3
Rails 5.2.3

Comment: hi, perhaps use `check_box` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616554/how-to-make-a-check-box-checked-in-rails

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a check\_box checked in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616554/how-to-make-a-check-box-checked-in-rails)

Comment: Why don't you use https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box along with https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for. When you are working with erb file form is the option

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out with include method. Thank you very much.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="1" <%= "checked='checked'" if @user.language_ids.include?(1) %>>Japanese</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="2" <%= "checked='checked'" if @user.language_ids.include?(2) %>>English</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="3" <%= "checked='checked'" if @user.language_ids.include?(3) %>>Chinese</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="4" <%= "checked='checked'" if @user.language_ids.include?(4) %>>Spanish</label>
```